# How to send data through actionlink in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, actionlink

In the application that I am trying to make, I have a menu in my view as below:

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Create Project", "Display", "CreateDisplay")</li>
    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Open", "About", "Home")</li>
</ul>
```

where CreateDisplay is the name of a controller and Display is a method in that controller which will call another view.

But, I want the Display method to accept certain parameters like username of the person.
In the current view, I have obtained the username as `@ViewData["UserName"]`

But I am not able to pass these values using ActionLink.
I tried passing the parameters as

```
<li>@Html.ActionLink("Create Project", "Display?UserName="+@ViewData["UserName"], "CreateDisplay")</li>
```

but received an exception.

Please suggest some ways of doing this.

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the overload that accepts parameters for route values.  [See the overloaded method `ActionLink()` here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd504972.aspx).

```
@Html.ActionLink(
    "Click me!",
    "Display",
    "CreateDisplay",
    new { UserName = "SetYourValHere" },
    null);
```